# Content tools Add the tag p automatically after add the image and video

Tags: javascript

[Content tools](http://getcontenttools.com/)

After adding image and video need to automatically add tag p after image and video(is this only when the table is at the end),
how it can be implemented?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using events to capture when a tool is applied and then apply the specific behaviour you are after.

There's no nice way to access these events currently (something I'll look into in future releases) however in the meantime here's a workaround that gives you the behaviour you are after and should be relatively simple to apply to any tool:

```
// Override the behaviour of the `ToolboxUI.tools` method so that we can
// bind to the applied event for the tools of interest.
var superTools = ContentTools.ToolboxUI.prototype.tools;
ContentTools.ToolboxUI.prototype.tools = function (tools) {
  superTools.call(this, tools);

  function _followWithP(ev) {
    var element = ev.detail().element;

    // Find the top level element
    if (element.parent().type() !== 'Region') {
      element = element.closest(function(node) {
        return node.parent().type() === 'Region';
      });
    }

    // Find the newely insert element
    var newElement = element.nextSibling();

    // Check if this is the last item in the region
    var siblings = newElement.parent().children;
    if (newElement === siblings[siblings.length - 1]) {
      // This is the last child so apply add a paragraph
      var p = new ContentEdit.Text('p', {}, '');
      newElement.parent().attach(p);
      p.focus();
    }
  }

  // Modify the applied behaviour of the image, table and video tools to use
  // `_followWithP`.
  this._toolUIs['image'].addEventListener('applied', _followWithP);
  this._toolUIs['table'].addEventListener('applied', _followWithP);
  this._toolUIs['video'].addEventListener('applied', _followWithP);
}
```